# Cartoon show where villain is shadow with an Asian rice hat

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I am trying to identify a show I used to watch long ago. I don’t remember much but that the villain was basically a shadow wearing an Asian rice hat (the conical pointy ones.) I also remember that the villain was a spirit locked in a forest, and later broke out and possessed a woodcutter (or farmer or something along those lines) who happened to be passing by.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Was the animation 2D or 3D? And in which country did you watch this?

Comment: It was 2D animation, if i recall correctly it was late 2000s, in the Philippines. Thanks for the warm welcome btw.